# Redirecting one project to another project in same solution Asp.net-How to specify path

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

I Have Three projects in a same solution Project 1,Project 2 and Project 3.
Project 3 contains single login page for both the Application (Single Database) once i click login button in project 3 it has to redirect to Project 1 Dashboard.aspx page can anyone tell me that how to redirect from one project to another project in same solution. how to specify that folder paths in application.

Comment: Possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23260311/how-to-redirect-to-another-page-in-another-solution-in-asp-net and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669159/response-redirect-from-one-web-project-to-another-in-visual-studio.

Comment: you can give full path in Response.Redirect `Response.Redirect("http://localhost:4040/Webform2.aspx");`

Comment: u have the host of Project1 dashboard?

Answer (score 1):

To redirect, I suggest adding a setting in your app settings, that specifies the host of Project 2:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Project2Host" value="localhost:5571/" />
</appSettings>
```

Now for the redirect, you can write:

```
Response.Redirect(Request.Url.Scheme + "://" 
    + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Project2Host"] 
    + "Numbers.aspx");
```

That way, when it comes time to deploy to a server, you can (hopefully) easily wire it up by simply changing the "Project2Host" setting in the web.config to "MyServer.com/Project2", or whatever.

---

For the second part, transferring a session variable, maybe you could pass it as a query string?  Redirect to the target URL plus `"?Variable=" + Session["Variable"]`.  Then pick it up in Project 2 using `Session["Variable"] = Request.QueryString["Variable"];`.

---

<sub>As a footnote: if you're planning to share data between the two sites, I'd consider setting them up as separate folders/virtual directories under the same web application project.</sub>

[Reference By](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17712503/redirecting-in-multiple-projects-in-one-solution/17712571#17712571)

Comment: Can i pass value in Query string from one project to another project in same solution while redirecting one Project to another Project??

Comment: yes you can see here  

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/583097/Global-Query-String-Encryption

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Encrypt-and-Decrypt-QueryString-Parameter-Values-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Keep your project path to AppSettings in web config. Then Redirect to that path reading from AppSettings.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/TargetProjectName;/TargetPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```